# Responsive drop cap with pure CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, typography

I've got a drop cap example using pure CSS that I've tweaked to be approximately three lines high using the default browser font.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p:first-of-type::first-letter {
        float: left;
        line-height: 65px;
        font-size: 70px;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-style: normal;
        margin-top: -3px;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 8px;
        margin-bottom: -10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh venenatis cras sed felis. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit. Amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae. Nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Nisi est sit amet facilisis. Quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi. Eu sem integer vitae justo eget magna. Neque egestas congue quisque egestas. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel.
      </p>
      <p>
      Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla. Aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur. Leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit. Ornare lectus sit amet est. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non. Nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse. Diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor.  
      </p>
      <p>
      Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis. Fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed. Risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit. Ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend. Posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis. Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non.  
      </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example here:

https://codepen.io/cayblood/pen/rNdQqrq

I'm wondering if there is a way with pure CSS to make the drop cap become two lines high instead of three if the paragraph height is too short, or to cease to be a drop cap if the paragraph is only one line high.

Bonus points for code that automatically adjusts the margins and font size depending on the particular first letter. I've noticed that each letter in each font has quirks that make it seem impossible to choose settings that cause every letter to be properly aligned with the margins of the surrounding text. I'm willing to tolerate javascript to achieve this stretch goal.

Comment: I really doubt that is possible with CSS. JavaScript sounds pretty straightforward for your first goal though. Just get the elements height and divide it by the line-height to get the line count.

Comment: You can try with SCSS an example is showing here https://www.minh.io/design/2015/09/28/dropcaps/

Comment: If you need to support Firefox, be aware that the result of your code is different there than in Chrome. In my experience, you have to put the drop-cap letter in its own div/span to get things working cross-browser.